# Exception in onCreateDialog method?

Tags: android

i am getting

```
09-20 12:42:26.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dashboardnew/com.dashboardnew.GmailFetchActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity#onCreateDialog did not create a dialog for id 1
```

exception in 2.1 and lower versions.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);

final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_gmail, null);

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

alert.setTitle("Gmail login"); 
alert.setMessage("Enter your username and password"); 
// Set an EditText view to get user input  
alert.setView(textEntryView);       

final EditText username = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.edit_username);
final EditText password = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.edit_password);

alert.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 

    String user=username.getText().toString();
    String pass=password.getText().toString();

    new FetchGmail().execute(user+"@gmail.com",pass); 
    progressDialog2.show();


} 
}); 

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 
    // Canceled. 
  } 
}); 

alert.show(); 


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return alert.create();
```

instead of:

```
alert.show(); 

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return super.onCreateDialog(id);
```

Comment: i am not quite sure why super.onCreateDialog(id) did not work here, but in your code alert is an instance of AlertDialog.Builder to get a dialog you need to call create() and you don't need to call the super method if you provide your own dialog

Answer (score 1):

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id, Bundle args)
```

> This method is deprecated. Use the new DialogFragment class with
>   FragmentManager instead; this is also available on older platforms
>   through the Android compatibility package. Callback for creating
>   dialogs that are managed (saved and restored) for you by the activity.
>   The default implementation calls through to onCreateDialog(int) for
>   compatibility. If you are targeting HONEYCOMB or later, consider
>   instead using a DialogFragment instead.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29

Answer (score 0):

May be this code may help you...

```
Builder pinBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    pinBuilder.setView(pinHolder).setTitle("Title")
        .setMessage("Set Message")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {



            } 
    }).
    setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {        
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
            {

            }
    }).show();
```

Comment: dont put this code in onCreateDialog() method.Put this code in Normal Activity

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert.create().show();`

Report back, if it didn't work.

Comment: what should i return ?? it got solved check the accepted ans can u plz explain what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

may be this code may help you.
First create class that extends dialog and then from your activity call this

```
CustomizeDilogForAddPhoto customizeDialog = new CustomizeDilogForAddPhoto(conntext,activity);
                customizeDialog.show();
```

Here is your Dialog Class

```
public class CustomizeDilogForAddPhoto extends Dialog implements OnClickListener 
{
    public CustomizeDilogForAddPhoto(Context context,Activity activity)
    {
        super(context);

        this.context=context;
        this.activity=activity;
        this.mainActivityname=maintabactivity;

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        requestWindowFeature(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        /** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
        setContentView(R.layout.custume_add_photo_dilog);

        btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnGallary.setOnClickListener(this);

    }   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {

    }
}
```